# tuning trouble - 1/4 wave 8 elevated ground radials 10 meter

Tags: antenna

It is resonate for 22 Mhz haven't had any luck tuning it for 30 Mhz  it is an excellent antenna I feel at the Z is 0 for 22 Mhz  I have given up and think I will just buy a Imax 2000 w/ radials??

"10 meter" I attempted to build a 1/4 antenna with 8 ground radials 4 feet long with 1/4 wave length of copper coiled around them and are sloped down 55 degrees

Comment: If you know that 109 inch antennas (9 feet) are a good quarter wavelength on CB, how could you think that 4 feet long would be resonant just a couple of MHz higher in frequency?  The same math for a half-wave dipole n free space, 468/F = feet, is a close enough approximation to know this can't be true.  Sounds like your tuner doesn't like the feedline.  I remember using a Dentron Super Tuner to literally get a signal out from a set of bed springs with one wire to them and a good ground.  I never tried the coat hanger.  I was sold already.  Loved that thing.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds as if your radials are basically a long inductor, with a resonant 1/4 wave of wire (8'ish) coiled around a noncondcutive form that's much shorter.

If that's the case, it won't work as is, as you're making the radials electrically longer than 1/4 wave. Basically you've added loading coils to them.

Because of this, the radials aren't presenting a low impedance, so the characteristic impedance is off for the whole antenna.

Test it with straight 1/4 wave wire radials. If it tunes, your radials are the problem. You'll need to make them even shorter to get them to resonate on 28MHz with the extra loading.